# Mutate dataframes in a nested list without for loop

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes (and parameters for sensitivity analyses for a study), and I want to mutate each dataframe in the same way. The expected output is generated by the code below (a new column `x2`). Is there a way to assign the resulting dataframes (`newdfs`) to the list without using a `for` loop?

```
models <- list(m1 = list('params' = list('start'='2014-01-01'),
                         'data' = data.frame(y=c(1,2,3), x1=c(4,5,6))),
               m2 = list('params' = list('start'='2017-01-01'),
                         'data' = data.frame(y=c(1,2,3), x1=c(7,8,9))))

newdfs <- lapply(models, function(z) {z$data$x2 <- z$data$x1 + 1
                                      z$data})

# Can I do this without "for"? 
for(x in 1:length(models)) models[[x]]$data <- newdfs[[x]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
newdfs <- lapply(models, function(z) {z$data$x2 <- z$data$x1 + 1
return(z)})

$m1
$m1$params
$m1$params$start
[1] "2014-01-01"


$m1$data
  y x1 x2
1 1  4  5
2 2  5  6
3 3  6  7


$m2
$m2$params
$m2$params$start
[1] "2017-01-01"


$m2$data
  y x1 x2
1 1  7  8
2 2  8  9
3 3  9 10
```

Comment: So simple and satisfying! Thanks Duck.

Comment: @BillO'Brien Great it helped you. If you feel comfortable with this answer you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of this question :)

Comment: Absolutely. Let me just be a good SO citizen and give other people a chance to answer, then I'll mark it.

Comment: @BillO'Brien Of course you are right :) Also I checked your google scholar profile. It is amazing. Your a genetic statistician, so you must have plenty of work now. Great profession.

Comment: Thanks, I'm flattered :) Lots of Covid studies in progress now.

Comment: @BillO'Brien Yeah plenty of data about that now!

Answer (score 1):

Revise the function in `lapply()` to return `z` instead of `z$data`:

```
lapply(models, function(z) {z$data$x2 <- z$data$x1 + 1 ; z})
```

---

To make this question complete, here are two `purrr` solutions:

```
library(purrr)
```

1. `map()` + `map_at()`

```
map(models, map_at, "data", transform, x2 = x1 + 1)
```

2. `transpose()` + `map()`

```
models %>%
  transpose %>% 
  `[[<-`(., "data", map(.$data, transform, x2 = x1 + 1)) %>%
  transpose
```

---

***Output***

```
$m1
$m1$params
$m1$params$start
[1] "2014-01-01"


$m1$data
  y x1 x2
1 1  4  5
2 2  5  6
3 3  6  7


$m2
$m2$params
$m2$params$start
[1] "2017-01-01"


$m2$data
  y x1 x2
1 1  7  8
2 2  8  9
3 3  9 10
```